# Python Selenium driver.execute_script() not returning any values despite supplying return value in passed in js script

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, dom

I have a selenium webdriver object that I am running `execute_script` on. However, when I input in this js script I have made:

```
var data = document.getElementsByClassName("assignment__row break-word clickable flex--space-between ng-star-inserted");
return data[0];
```

into the call `result = driver.execute_script(theScript)` the array of HTML elements that are supposed to be returned return a None type instead.

how do I get the selenium script to output the html of the aforementioned js script so I can parse it for data?

I tried splitting up the js script commands like how someone can do on console.
Example:

```
driver.execute_script("var data = document.getElementsByClassName("assignment__row break-word clickable flex--space-between ng-star-inserted");")
print(driver.execute_script("data[0]")) <--- This a[0] would return the element at index 0 in js dev tools
```

But instead I recieved a "Type not found" error for my method call of `driver.execute_script("a[0]")`
(This means that the first js command isn't executing but I can't figure out why the data isn't getting stored in the js console when I run the second command)

This works when I run the javascript commands seperately in Chrome devtools but not in selenium?

Comment: this `result = driver.execute_script(theScript)` should have worked unless something else is going on with selenium, as a debug, can you put `console.log(data[0])` before your JS return to check if JS is getting the values. to recreate, we need URL or HTML.

Comment: @simpleApp do you mean in the browser javascript devtools console after I have run the getElementsByClassName function?

Comment: yes pls. open the site --> dev tools --> console -> `document.getElementsByClassName("assignment__row break-word clickable flex--space-between ng-star-inserted")[0]`-->check the output. if this looks okay, then selenium will get too, if not correct it means selector is not okay.

Comment: @simpleApp I had a bad selector thanks for help

Comment: You can't return elements. Only things that Python know about -> primitives, arrays, objects...

Answer (score 0):

You can't run calling two times. Because it execute the code inside anonymous function.
data variable is local and it cannot be access from another function

```py
script = """
var data = document.getElementsByClassName("assignment_row break-word clickable flex--space-between ng-star-inserted");
return data[0];"""

result = driver.execute_script(script)
```